# How to use multiple arrays as parameters for a httppost method ins asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, arrays, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

How can I use the two arrays that I have as a parameter for a method in the controller? I thought using AJAX would do, but I don't know how will I pass the two arrays.

```
var arrayIngredientId = new Array();
var arrayQuantity = new Array();

//Some code here to get the values of the arrays.
//I did a loop that inserts the data to the arrays through a variable ctr that increments

$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "/Recipes/Create",
    contentType: "html",
    dataType: 'json',
    data :{
        //I don't know what should I put here
    },
    traditional: true,
    success: function (result) {
       alert.log(data.result)
    },
    error: function(data){
       alert("fail");
    }
})

//The method I have for controller. I don't know what parameters should I put
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Create()
{
  return Json(new { result = "success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: What is the signature of your controller method, and what is the model? And how are you populating those arrays?

Comment: And if you have generated you form controls correctly then its simply `data: $('form'.serialize())` - and remove the `contentType` option (which make no sense being `'html'` anyway)

Comment: I edited the content of the post.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrayIngredientId = new Array();
var arrayQuantity = new Array();

$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { objName: JSON.stringify({ arrayQuantity : arrayQuantity ,arrayIngredientId : arrayIngredientId }) },
                    url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Recipes")',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                       alert(msg);
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                    }
                });

 //Controller side
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(string objName)
    {
        dynamic d = JObject.Parse(objName);
        int totalarrayIngredientId= d.arrayIngredientId.Count;
        var vertex = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < totalarrayIngredientId; i++)
        {
            //get like d.arrayIngredientId[i].YourKeyName
        }

        return Json("");
    }
```